# Save BigQuery results to array

Tags: arrays, google-bigquery

I have a query that looks like this

```sql
SELECT ids FROM `table_name`
```

The results set is as follows

```
| ids |
|-----|
| 1   |
| 2   |
| 3   |
```

I need to save this result set to an `ARRAY` so that I can later loop over it. Defining the array manually is not an option since my result set will get larger over time adding 4, 5, 6, etc. That's why I can't just use:

```sql
SELECT GENERATE_ARRAY(1, 2, 3) AS my_array
```

I tried

```sql
SELECT GENERATE_ARRAY(SELECT ids FROM `table_name`) AS my_array
```

but it doesn't work.

I'm basically looking for the inverse of `UNNEST`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL - usually `ARRAY_AGG` can be used as inverse of `UNNEST`

```
#standardSQL
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(ids) ids
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

You can test, play with above using sample data from your question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 ids UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 
)
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(ids) ids
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with result

```
Row ids  
1   1    
    2    
    3
```

Comment: Thank you Mikhail!! Works just as I needed :)